# What permissions do we need to create file_format in Snowflake

Tags: file-format, snowflake-schema

I am trying to create file_format to create stage in snowflake with custom role. I have assigned privileges to create stage and use the storage integrations, schema, database but it is still showing me error "SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'PUBLIC'.

It's able to create stage without file_format parameter but file_format is required for creating table.
Thanks

The code so far I have tried

```
grant create stage on schema public to role my_role2;
grant usage on integration s3_int to role my_role2;
GRANT USAGE, MONITOR ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE test TO ROLE my_role2; 
grant create table on schema TEST.PUBLIC to role my_role2;

create or replace file format my_csv_format
type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1
field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'
null_if = ('NULL', 'null') 
empty_field_as_null = true;
```

```
create or replace stage demo_stage url='' 
STORAGE_INTEGRATION="s3_int"
file_format = my_csv_format;
```

Creating file _format is giving error ""SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'PUBLIC'. It's able to create stage without file_format parameter but file_format is required for creating table.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#access-control-requirements), your role needs the CREATE FILE FORMAT privilege on the schema